# stopPropagation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want an overlay to fire the `click` event. But the `click` goes of on every childnode.

```js
function something(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('its fired');
}
```

```css
#overlay {
  width: 100%;
}
#image-wrapper {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay" onclick="something">
  <div id="image-wrapper">
    <img src="image.jpg" id="popupImage" alt="[image]">
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't want it fire `click` on the image. Only in the overlay.

Comment: A shot in the dark: Have you tried e.PreventDefault()

Comment: @Zaphod I guess you meant `e.preventDefault()`. But here there is no default action that can be prevented, and `preventDefault` doesn't stop propagation.

Comment: Actually i did, played around with some stuff like preventDefault and cancelBubbling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can `preventDefault()` on the `img`

```
$("img").click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 e.stopPropagation();
 console.log("stop click");    

});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hmvpLy6k/1/)

Comment: `preventDefault` does nothing in this case, because there is no default action that can be prevented. It's `stopPropagation` what stops the propagation of the event triggered in the image.

Answer (score 2):

[`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.target) is the element that triggered the event.

[`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.currentTarget) is the [`EventTarget`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-EventTarget) whose [`EventListeners`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-EventListener) are currently being processed.

Therefore, comparing those you can filter events triggered in your element itself, not in its descendants.

```js
document.getElementById('overlay').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if(e.target != e.currentTarget) return;
  console.log('its fired');
});
```

```css
#overlay {
  width: 100%;
  background: #aaf;
}
#image-wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  background: #afa;
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay">
  <div id="image-wrapper">
    <img src="image.jpg" id="popupImage" alt="[image]">
  </div>
</div>
```

Additional notes:

- Avoid inline event listeners in the html. Better add them using JS, e.g. with `addEventListener`.
- Usually, you can use `this` instead of `e.currentTarget`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:-

```
 <div id="overlay" style="width: 100%;" onclick="something">
   <div id="image-wrapper" style="width: 50%;">
    <img src="image.jpg" id="popupImage" onclick="nothing">
  </div>
 </div>

function something (e) {


  console.log('its fired');
 }

function nothing (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the event handler you have there on the *image* (or the image wrapper depending on the exact effect that you are looking for) so that the doesn't propagate to the overlay when the image is clicked.

Alternatively, check the `target` property of the event object and `return` if it is something you don't want to handle the event on.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure the click comes from the overlay and nothing else:

```
function something(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  evar target = e.target || e.srcElement;
  if (target.id === 'overlay') {
    console.log('Overlay has been clicked');
  } else {
    console.log('Something else has been clicked');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="overlay" style="width: 100%;" onclick="something">
    <div id="image-wrapper" style="width: 50%;">
        <img src="image.jpg" id="popupImage">
    </div>
</div>



getElementById('overlay').onclick = function(e) {
    console.log('did something');
    callToSomehtingElse();
}

getElementById('image-wrapper').onclick = function(e){
    console.log('but here i prevented it'); 
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Thanks to everyone...